# Add shared library to cpack

Tags: cmake, cpack

How could I add a shared libraray (Qt6Core.dll) to CPack? I tested the following snipped:

```
set(MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS "C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/bin/")
install(CODE "set(MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS \"${MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS}\")")

install(CODE [[
  file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
    LIBRARIES $<TARGET_FILE:Qt6::Core>
    RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR _r_deps
    UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR _u_deps
    DIRECTORIES ${MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS}
  )
  foreach(_file ${_r_deps})
    file(INSTALL
      DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib"
      TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY
      FILES "${_file}"
    )
  endforeach()
  list(LENGTH _u_deps _u_length)
  if("${_u_length}" GREATER 0)
    message("Anzahl: ${_u_length}")
    message(WARNING "Unresolved dependencies detected!")
  endif()
]])
```

But it shows me:

```
CMake Warning at C:/CPP/Projects/beans/build/packaging/cmake_install.cmake:89 (message):
    Unresolved dependencies detected!
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/CPP/Projects/beans/build/cmake_install.cmake:57 (include)
```

Now are over 200 other shared libraries in my /lib directory but no Qt6Core.dll.

Comment: So, what is **content** of `_u_deps` variable (not just its length)? And what is content of `r_deps` variable, accumulating successfully resolved libraries?

Comment: I have made qtcore.dll now copied <TARGET_FILE:Qt6::Core>is wrong. I replaced it with my executable target and it worked^^. But all other libs will still copied.  _r_deps are all windows libs and my qt6core.dll. _u_deps start all with api-ms-win or ext-ms-win and included hvsifi and letrust.dll. Is it possible to copy only one .dll? With an other method?

Comment: "Is it possible to copy only one .dll? With an other method?" - Yes, just specify this `.dll` in `file(INSTALL)` command.

Comment: Thanks for your help. file(INSTALL) work also. I answered the question^^

Answer (score 1):

I solved my Problem.

```
set(MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS "C:/Qt/6.0.0/msvc2019_64/bin/")
install(CODE "set(MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS \"${MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS}\")")

install(CODE [[
  file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
    LIBRARIES $<TARGET_FILE:MYPROJECT>
    RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR _r_deps
    UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR _u_deps
    DIRECTORIES ${MY_DEPENDENCY_PATHS}
    PRE_EXCLUDE_REGEXES "api-ms-" "ext-ms-"
    POST_EXCLUDE_REGEXES ".*system32/.*\\.dll"
  )
  foreach(_file ${_r_deps})
    file(INSTALL
      DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib"
      TYPE SHARED_LIBRARY
      FILES "${_file}"
    )
  endforeach()
  list(LENGTH _u_deps _u_length)
  if("${_u_length}" GREATER 0)
    message(WARNING "Unresolved dependencies detected!")
  endif()
]])
```